# How to find the next element given a certain element in array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I wrote a method to get the next element after a given element inside an array. If I provide the method with `c`, I want it to return `e`; if `e`, I want it to return `a`, etc.:

```
array = %w[a f c e]

def find_element_after(element, array)
  index = array.find_index(element) + 1
  array.at(index)
end

array.find_element_after("c", array)
```

If I pass in the last element I will get `nil`. But I want to return the first element instead.

I can solve this with `if` and `else`. But I want to know if Ruby has better way?

Comment: It's not necessary to strike-out changed text. We can see the edit history if something doesn't make sense.

Comment: One thing to consider is how this will slow down as `array` grows in size because you are using a linear search. Instead I'd probably use some sort of linked-list or a hash inside a custom class that manages/maintains that hash. The key is what you search for and the value is the next element. That would be a very consistent lookup speed with a little slower insertion time.

Comment: @theTinMan thanks for pointing those two things out. In this case I'll have probably less than 100 items, which should be trivial. It's good to know, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could modify your method, taking array size into account, like this:

```
array = %w[a f c e]

def find_element_after(element, array)
  index = array.find_index(element) + 1
  array.at(index % array.size) # divide calculated index modulo array size
end

find_element_after('e', array)
# => "a"
```

If you want to make your method proof to passing argument that isn't member of array, you could do:

```
def find_element_after(element, array)
  index = array.find_index(element)
  array.at((index + 1) % array.size) if index
end
find_element_after('u', array)
# => nil
```

or:

```
def find_element_after(element, array)
  return nil unless array.include?(element)
  index = array.find_index(element)
  array.at(index % array.size)
end
```

as you see, there's many possible solutions. Feel free to experiment.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass in the last element, it actually works. The index gets evaluated to the last index, and retrieving the element at `lastindex + 1` from the array returns `nil`.

The problem is when you provide an element that is not present in the array. It's this scenario that will result in the `index` being `nil` and then throwing the `NoMethodError` when you call `+ 1` on it.

To fix this case, define your method like this:

```
def find_element_after(element, array)
  index = array.find_index(element)
  array.at(index + 1) if index
end
```

Here's a demo showing how it works now ([run online](http://ideone.com/E6eZJs)):

```
array = %w[a f c e]

def find_element_after(element, array)
  index = array.find_index(element)
  array.at(index + 1) if index
end

p find_element_after("c", array) # element in the middle - prints "e"
p find_element_after("e", array) # last element - prints "nil"
p find_element_after("z", array) # element not present in the array - prints "nil" (no error)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. The issue is I never want to return nil when the last element is passed. I want to return the first element instead, going in a circle essentially. But that's easy enough I now understand the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) to iterate the array using pairs:

```
def find_element_after(element, array)
  cons = array.each_cons(2).find { |i1, i2| i1 == element }
  cons.nil? ? array.first : cons.last
end

find_element_after('c', array)
# => "e"
find_element_after('e', array)
# => "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other ways to do that.

**#1 Use the method [Array#rotate](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-rotate)**

```
def nxt(arr, e)
  arr.rotate(arr.index(e)+1).first
end

arr = %w[a f c e]

nxt(arr, 'a') #=> "f"
nxt(arr, 'f') #=> "c"
nxt(arr, 'c') #=> "e"
nxt(arr, 'e') #=> "a"
```

I think this reads well, but it has the disadvantage of creating a temporary array the size of `arr`.

**#2 Use `Array#rotate` to construct a hash**

```
h = Hash[arr.zip(arr.rotate(1))]
  #=> {"a"=>"f", "f"=>"c", "c"=>"e", "e"=>"a"}

h['a'] #=> "f"
h['f'] #=> "c"
h['c'] #=> "e"
h['e'] #=> "a"
```

**#3 Use [Array#cycle](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-cycle) to create an enumerator**

```
enum = arr.cycle

def nxt(enum, v)
  until enum.next == v do
  end
  enum.next
end

nxt(enum, 'a') #=> "f"
nxt(enum, 'f') #=> "c"
nxt(enum, 'c') #=> "e"
nxt(enum, 'e') #=> "a"
```

The latter two approaches should be relatively efficient if you had several values to map.

Answer (score 0):

If need a cycle so to get the first element if the last passed

```rb
def find_after(element, array)
  idx = array.index(element)
  array[idx - array.length + 1]
end
```